# Error Converting Datatable to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error

> Error :- Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    C:\Users\e19206\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TerroristMVC\TerroristBAL\Models\Landingbal.cs  51  20  TerroristBAL

Here is my code

```
public IEnumerable<Landing> getReportSummary()
{
    DataTable dtRepSummary = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        procname = "TDS_QUERY.GET_REP_SUMMARY";

        OracleParameter[] oraParam = new OracleParameter[1];

        oraParam[0] = new OracleParameter("TDS_RECORDSET", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        oraParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        connection = new OracleConnection(SqlHelper.GetConnection());

        DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, procname, oraParam);

        dtRepSummary = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errormessage = "Method name:- " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " | Description: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException;
        log.Error(errormessage);
    }

    return dtRepSummary.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Here is my landing Model class

```
public class Landing
{
    #region properties

    public string Reportid { get; set; }

    public string Reportdate { get; set; }

    public string Fromdate { get; set; }

    public string Todate { get; set; }

    public string Executed { get; set; }

    public string Userid { get; set; }

    public string Recadddate { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because `dtRepSummary.AsEnumerable()` returns `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but you have the return type as `IEnumerable<Landing>`, you can use [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907949(v=vs.110).aspx) to project your type like this:-

```
return dtRepSummary.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Landing
                                        {
                                           Reportid = x.Field<int>("Reportid"), 
                                           Reportdate = x.Field<string>("Reportdate"),
                                           ..and so on
                                        };
```

Comment: Note this also requires the System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll assembly to be referenced to be able to use AsEnumerable and Field (which are part of the DataTableExtensions class)

Comment: @SimonMourier - Yeah, OP is already using that cz currently he is returning `dtRepSummary.AsEnumerable()` .

Comment: I suppose so, but it was not clear reading the question, it's tags or the answer

Comment: Great it worked. Is it necessary to convert Datatable to ienumerable as per asp.net mvc 4 ?

Comment: @Vineet - No it's not mandatory, you can change you View like this `@model System.Data.DataTable` and then return a `DataTable` from controller but IMHO working with `IEnumerable` is easy as compared with DataTable.

Comment: Don't use datatables or other database related models. Always transform the result from the DB to ViewModel which makes it cleaner. I agree with @RahulSingh that IEnumerable is easier to use than DataTables.